# snakemake STAR module issue and extra question

Tags: snakemake

I discovered that the [snakemake STAR module](https://snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wrappers/star/align.html) outputs as 'BAM Unsorted'.

**Q1:Is there a way to change this to:**

> --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate

When I add the option in the 'extra' options I get an error message about duplicate definition:

```
EXITING: FATAL INPUT ERROR: duplicate parameter "outSAMtype" in input "Command-Line"
SOLUTION: keep only one definition of input parameters in each input source

Nov 15 09:46:07 ...... FATAL ERROR, exiting
logs/star/se/UY2_S7.log (END)
```

Should I consider adding a sorting module behind STAR instead?

**Q2: How can I take a module from the wrapper repo and make it a local module, allowing me to edit it?**

the code:

```
__author__ = "Johannes Köster"
__copyright__ = "Copyright 2016, Johannes Köster"
__email__ = "koester@jimmy.harvard.edu"
__license__ = "MIT"

import os
from snakemake.shell import shell

extra = snakemake.params.get("extra", "")
log = snakemake.log_fmt_shell(stdout=True, stderr=True)

fq1 = snakemake.input.get("fq1")
assert fq1 is not None, "input-> fq1 is a required input parameter"
fq1 = [snakemake.input.fq1] if isinstance(snakemake.input.fq1, str) else snakemake.input.fq1
fq2 =  snakemake.input.get("fq2")
if fq2:
    fq2 = [snakemake.input.fq2] if isinstance(snakemake.input.fq2, str) else snakemake.input.fq2
    assert len(fq1) == len(fq2), "input-> equal number of files required for fq1 and fq2"
input_str_fq1 = ",".join(fq1)
input_str_fq2 = ",".join(fq2) if fq2 is not None else ""
input_str =  " ".join([input_str_fq1, input_str_fq2])

if fq1[0].endswith(".gz"):
    readcmd = "--readFilesCommand zcat"
else:
    readcmd = ""

outprefix = os.path.dirname(snakemake.output[0]) + "/"

shell(
    "STAR "
    "{extra} "
    "--runThreadN {snakemake.threads} "
    "--genomeDir {snakemake.params.index} "
    "--readFilesIn {input_str} "
    "{readcmd} "
    "--outSAMtype BAM Unsorted "
    "--outFileNamePrefix {outprefix} "
    "--outStd Log "
    "{log}")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q1:Is there a way to change this to:
>
> > --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate

I would add another sorting rule after the wrapper as it is the most 'standardized` way of doing it.  You can also use another wrapper for sorting.

There is an explanation from the author of snakemake for the reason why the default is unsorted and why there is no option for sorted output in the wrapper:

https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/440/pre-post-wrapper

> Regarding the SAM/BAM issue, I would say any wrapper should always output the optimal file format. Hence, whenever I write a wrapper for a read mapper, I ensure that output is not SAM. Indexing and sorting should not be part of the same wrapper I think, because such a task has a completely different behavior regarding parallelization. Also, you would loose the mapping output if something goes wrong during the sorting or indexing.

---

> Q2: How can I take a module from the wrapper repo and make it a local module, allowing me to edit it?

If you wanted to do this, one way would be to download the local copy of the wrapper.  Change in the shell portion of the downloaded wrapper  `Unsorted` to `{snakemake.params.outsamtype}`. In your Snakefile change (`wrapper` to `script`, `path/to/downloaded/wrapper`  and add the `outsamtype` parameter):

```
rule star_se:
    input:
        fq1 = "reads/{sample}_R1.1.fastq"
    output:
        # see STAR manual for additional output files
        "star/{sample}/Aligned.out.bam"
    log:
        "logs/star/{sample}.log"
    params:
        # path to STAR reference genome index
        index="index",
        # optional parameters
        extra="",
        outsamtype = "SortedByCoordinate"
    threads: 8
    script:
        "path/to/downloaded/wrapper"
```

I think a separate rule w/o a wrapper for sorting or even making your own star rule rather is better.  Modifying the wrapper defeats the whole purpose of it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added a picard module. About my 2nd, I meant to ask if i could download full wrappers and install them locally, editing some to have snakemake load them from the local copy onstead. Like a local repo if you like. Is this possible?

Comment: @splaisan, I'm running into the same problem. How did you solve it in the end?

Comment: @manvenk, sorry but I do not recall, this is quite old.  I may as well have stopped trying snakemake at some point and went on with my pure bash approach. Sorry that I cannot help more.